# ODE particular solution in different methods

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$y''' + 2y'' + y' = 7 x e^{x}$

I am trying to get the particular solution of this ODE, surprisingly I got different answer for both variation of parameter(VOP) and  undetermined coefficients (UC) method!

I believe this is due to the fact that UC does not accept any mutual term that already exists in the homogeneous solution , so we end up having that term in the particular solution of VOP.

These are the answers I got by different methods:
VOP:
$$
Y_p =   7 e^{-x}\left(-\frac 16x^3 - \frac 12x^2 - x- 1\right)  
$$
UC:

$$Y_p = 7 e^{-x} \cdot ( - x^{3}/6 - x^{2}/2 )$$

Why is this? Should I take a step further in the solution?

Edit :

My solution via UC:

> [image: UC]

Via VOP:

[image: VOP-a]

[image: VOP -b]

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your progress. What was your characteristic solution? What did you find for the Wronskian? What was your *ansatz* (the function you guessed for undetermined coefficients)?

Comment: I added my solution..

Comment: Do you suspect a problem or are you just curious why you get "different" solutions?

Comment: yeah, I am curious about the reason.I believe they should end up being the same! I tried linking the idea with systems in linear algebra, but still, I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: But the question , can I consider yp from VOP and UC both are equivalent ? In terms of the particular solution only -not the general one-.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti oh yes I got it! but is there any further mathematical proof?